# $\frac{d}{dt}\varphi^*_t\omega=\varphi^*_tL_X\omega$ where $X$ is a smooth vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. I want to show that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\varphi^*_t\omega=\varphi^*_t L_X\omega\text{ }(*)$$
where $X$ is a smooth vector field on $M$, $\varphi_t$ is a family of diffeomorphism generated by a vector field $X$, $L_X$ is a Lie derivative along $X$, and $\omega$ is some $n$-form on $M$.

The idea is to show that $(*)$ holds for $0$-form. Then use the fact that the pullback and Lie derivative commutes with an exterior derivative $d$ and since $\Omega(M)$ is generated by $0$-form and $1$-form, we will obtain the desired fact.

I struggle to argue that
$$d(\frac{d}{dt}\varphi^*_t\omega)=\frac{d}{dt}d\varphi^*_t\omega.$$
Is it obvious? Do I just need to write it down in local coordinates? Is there any source with more details for this argument?

Comment: Once you write in local coordinates, you'll see that it is a result of the commutation of partial derivatives. Explicitly, $\partial_i \frac{d}{dt} \alpha=\frac{d}{dt}\partial_i \alpha$. It doesn't matter that we specifically have $\varphi_t^*\omega$, just that it is a time-dependent form.